# How send and receive soap+xml in RESTful services in C#

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, soap, mdm

I want write the RESTful web service for Enterprise Mobile Device Management in C# to post the request show below which is defined by Microsoft:

**POST REQUEST INFO:**

```
**Header:**

POST /EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Windows Phone 8 Enrollment Client
Host: EnterpriseEnrollment.Contoso.com
Content-Length: xxx
Cache-Control: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/IDiscoveryService/Discover
</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">
https://ENROLLTEST.CONTOSO.COM/EnrollmentServer/Discovery.svc
</a:To>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<Discover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/">
<request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EmailAddress>user@contoso.com</EmailAddress>
<RequestVersion>1.0</RequestVersion>
</request>
</Discover>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**POST RESPONSE INFO**

```
Header:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 865
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Server: EnterpriseEnrollment.Contoso.com
Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2012 00:32:56 GMT
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">
http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment/IDiscoveryService/DiscoverResponse
</a:Action>
<ActivityId>
d9eb2fdd-e38a-46ee-bd93-aea9dc86a3b8
</ActivityId>
<a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid: 748132ec-a575-4329-b01b-6171a9cf8478</a:RelatesTo>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">>
<DiscoverResponse
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/management/2012/01/enrollment">
<DiscoverResult>
<AuthPolicy>OnPremise</AuthPolicy>
<AuthUrl/>
<EnrollmentPolicyServiceUrl>
https://enrolltest.contoso.com/ENROLLMENTSERVER/DEVICEENROLLMENTWEBSERVICE.SVC
</EnrollmentPolicyServiceUrl>
<EnrollmentServiceUrl>
https://enrolltest.contoso.com/ENROLLMENTSERVER/DEVICEENROLLMENTWEBSERVICE.SVC
</EnrollmentServiceUrl>
<FederatedServiceName/>
<FederatedServicePolicy/>
</DiscoverResult>
</DiscoverResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I would like to know how should I create WebInvoke method for POST call in my web service?

With the below prototype I am able to send and receive the soap xml, but not sure whether this right to way to implement?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)] 
XmlElement Post(Stream xmlData);
```

Also I have tried using the class object as defined below, but with WCF Test client I could see the soap xml getting generated, but when tried to access this web service from the test application, I get only the xml content for the class object and not seeing any soap header and body elements.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
DiscoverResponse Discover(Discover request);
```

where DiscoverResponse  is DataContract class for POST response and Discover is the DataContract class for POST request.

What changes do I need to make to above method to get response with entire soap xml instead of only the body xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebInvoke` will never return soap+xml with the `WebHttpBinding`. It only supports returning either JSON or pure XML. If you want soap-based XML, just call the service on endpoints using either the `BasicHttpBinding` or the `WsHttpBinding`. They're both soap-based bindings. You could create two endpoints for the service, one with the `WebHttpBinding` for standard XML and one with either of the other bindings to get soap+xml.

Comment: Thanks, Can I use the same OperationContract declaration and add the new endpoints with BasicHttpBinding or WsHttpBinding?

Comment: After creating the WsHttpBinding, I get the error as "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
" for xml and soap+xml.

Comment: Here is a [good general purpose MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx) on setting up multiple endpoints for a service. Look at [this blog post](http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/wcf-service-with-webhttpbinding.html) for specifics on getting `WebHttpBinding` working with multiple bindings.

Comment: As per my understanding, RESTful services should use webhttpbinding, right? If I switch to basicHttpBinding or wsHtppBinding, can I use WebInvoke/WebGet for Post and GET request?

Comment: No, WebInvoke/WebGet only apply to WebHttpBinding. What seem have failed to explain was you create two separate endpoints for the service. An endpoint using basicHttpBinding/wsHttpBinding for clients that send and consume soap-based message. Another endpoint using webHttpBinding for clients that send and consume JSON or plain XML. Soap-based bindings and webHttpBinding are *mutually exclusive*. For a message to be soap-based, you **cannot** use the webHttpBinding.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The MSFT enterprise enrollment protocol shows soap request and response using GET and POST. How can I achieve soap request and response using HTTP GET and POST?     Please can you respond to this query too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303466/query-discovery-web-service-for-enterprise-device-management